# Is there a way to provide static typing in ng-template let-* bindings?

Tags: angular, typescript

So here is an example of template.

component.ts:

```
  @ViewChild('valueTemplate') valueTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
```

component.html

```html
<ng-template #valueTemplate let-rowIndex="rowIndex" let-dataItem="dataItem">
  ***
</ng-template>
```

How can I provide static typing and autocomplete (JB WebStorm) here?
Now both of `rowIndex` and `dataItem` inferred into `any` ts type.

Comment: This isn't currently possible, unfortunately. The Angular team is hesitant to bring writing type information into the templates directly. My usual workaround is an ngIf inside the template with an identity function that serves to narrow the type. It's not perfect but still better.

Comment: ^ This is for the typing on the template side. On the TS side you can use the generic argument of TemplateRef for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of https://github.com/nigrosimone/ng-let (on npm https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-let) that support static typing. For make a custom let directive with static typing:

```
import { Directive, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

interface NgLetContext<T> {
    ngLet: T;
    $implicit: T;
}

@Directive({
    // tslint:disable-next-line: directive-selector
    selector: '[ngLet]'
})
export class NgLetDirective<T> {

    private context: NgLetContext<T | null> = { ngLet: null, $implicit: null };
    private hasView: boolean = false;

    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
    constructor(private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef, private templateRef: TemplateRef<NgLetContext<T>>) { }

    @Input()
    set ngLet(value: T) {
        this.context.$implicit = this.context.ngLet = value;
        if (!this.hasView) {
            this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef, this.context);
            this.hasView = true;
        }
    }

    /** @internal */
    public static ngLetUseIfTypeGuard: void;

    /**
     * Assert the correct type of the expression bound to the `NgLet` input within the template.
     *
     * The presence of this static field is a signal to the Ivy template type check compiler that
     * when the `NgLet` structural directive renders its template, the type of the expression bound
     * to `NgLet` should be narrowed in some way. For `NgLet`, the binding expression itself is used to
     * narrow its type, which allows the strictNullChecks feature of TypeScript to work with `NgLet`.
     */
    static ngTemplateGuard_ngLet: 'binding';

    /**
     * Asserts the correct type of the context for the template that `NgLet` will render.
     *
     * The presence of this method is a signal to the Ivy template type-check compiler that the
     * `NgLet` structural directive renders its template with a specific context type.
     */
    static ngTemplateContextGuard<T>(dir: NgLetDirective<T>, ctx: any): ctx is NgLetContext<Exclude<T, false | 0 | '' | null | undefined>> {
        return true;
    }
}
```

usage

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
  <ng-container *ngLet="(num1 + num2) as total"> <!-- single computation -->
    <div>
      1: {{ total }} <!-- 3 -->
    </div>
    <div>
      2: {{ total }} <!-- 3 -->
    </div>
  </ng-container> 
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  num1: number = 1;
  num2: number = 2;
}
```

Comment: I cannot find any example to use a strict TYPE using `ngLet`. Can you please point me in the right way ?

Answer (score 1):

So, I decided to use [*ngLet directive](https://github.com/ngrx-utils/ngrx-utils#nglet-directive) for that purpose, despite little function calls overhead inside this directive.

Usage:

```
  asFilter(dataItem: any): Filter {
    return dataItem as Filter;
  }
```

```html
<ng-template #valueTemplate let-rowIndex="rowIndex" let-dataItem="dataItem">
  <ng-container *ngLet="asFilter(dataItem) as filter">
```